# What are known metrics for TRNG?

Tags: nist, trng

I was wondering what the known metrics are for studying the randomness of TRNG (besides NIST tests). 
 For example, for PUFs, there are known metrics such as uniformity, uniqueness, BER, etc.

Comment: What is the physical device you want to study?  What do you know about the physics of it?  What is the best that a trained experimental physicist can do to predict the output of the device?

Comment: Aren't the metrics independent of the physical device?

Comment: Nope!  It depends _entirely_ on the physical device.  You should assume the adversary knows _exactly_ what your physical device is; they win if they can predict the output it produces, _using that knowledge_.  The NIST tests are just a collection of very simple-minded models for how a TRNG might work, aggregated into software that fits parameters for the model and computes the resulting entropy of the model.  More details on how ‘entropy tests’ work: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/58164

Comment: This question is probably going to get a bad answer from *Cnhy Hfmnx*. Now isn't a good time for me to write a full answer. There are no methods to determine if RNG output is good. Only methods to determine the output is almost certainly bad. Such "metrics" are just results from ordinary statistical hypothesis testing.

Comment: The reason I asked this question is that I was studying PUF before. There are some known metrics for PUF hardwares such as uniformity. I thought, similarly, there exists metrics for TRNG.

Comment: There isn't a single metric of ‘uniformity’.  There's min-entropy, there's total variation distance from uniform, there's KL divergence from uniform, _etc._  As far as cryptography is concerned, all you need is a sample with, say, >=256 bits of min-entropy: maximizing min-entropy _for fixed output length_ or minimizing your favorite statistical distance from uniform is just a matter of _performance_, but once you have 256 bits of min-entropy you have enough for any cryptography you want; _e.g._, you can expand it into many keys with HKDF.

Comment: Actually, yes the randomness metrics of a TRNG are entirely independent of what's in the box.  That's plainly intuitive, otherwise you'd have flavours and commercial brands of randomness which is just silly.

Comment: @PaulUszak that's only because the final output from a TRNG is whitened (debiased, or using entropy extraction, etc). The internal output is still almost always visibly biased. This bias MUST be modeled mathematically to understand how much unpredictable entropy you're getting. You should expect people asking about this bias to be referring to pre-whitening bias, unless otherwise stated.

Comment: @PaulUszak since the asker wanted to know about hardware properties, as implied from other comments, yes I refer to the entropy source. Unless you can model your source, you do not know at what rate you can extract entropy (predictability), and thus you also don't know what whitening procedure is appropriate. However, post-whitening every well designed TRNG should be near perfectly indistinguishable (as you implied as well), which means it's meaningless to ask specifically about TRNG output properties (instead of just entropy) unless you're just trying to validate yours isn't visibly broken

Comment: @Shabnam Are you actually referring to the entropy source inside a TRNG, or the output from the entire device? –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two common documents that pertain to TRNGs.  There's US NIST Special Publication 800-90C, [Recommendation for Random Bit 
 Generator (RBG) Constructions](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Publications/sp/800-90c/draft/documents/sp800_90c_second_draft.pdf), and the less sanctimonious German BSI [A proposal for:
Functionality classes for random number generators.](https://cosec.bit.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/user_upload/teaching/15ss/15ss-taoc/01_AIS31_Functionality_classes_for_random_number_generators.pdf)

There are all sorts of stochastic measures listed therein, but they boil down to two essential ones:-

1. The next bit that emerges from the TRNG has a 50.0% chance of being a "1" when measured in the long run.  This determination is made via tests such as ent, diehard and dieharder, TestU01 and others. The appropriate test suite is often indicated by the output rate as some TRNGs only run at 2kbps or even less.  And each of those tests are composed of smaller individual tests like counting runs and frequencies. The 50.0% value automatically infers each output value   be independent from one another.
2. That the output sequence doesn't repeat itself when the TRNG is restarted.  This is kinda subsumed into (1) above in the most general case if you think about it.

If you accept that random is random, it clearly follows that the output of any working TRNG has to be entirely independent of the internal processes, other than speed.  Some people get confused with the distinctions between an entropy source and a TRNG.  The entropy source is the internal circuit that generates a non deterministic (random but often auto correlated) signal.  This is then processed and independent uniformly distributed bytes  are output from the TRNG.  At this point, one cannot identify how the bytes were made. They're just plain bytes. You would not be able to differentiate any particular TRNG by even the most detailed inspections of their outputs.

As a couple of metrics examples, see the test certificates for the online [bet365 casino](https://content001.bet365.com/help/docs/rtpcertificates/com/bet365virtualsportsecogracertificate03-18.pdf) ComScire TRNG using some custom tests and diehard, and the   Quantis TRNG using diehard.

Comment: Runs tests do not even imply that each subsequent bit appears independent. Even an LFSR will typically pass runs tests. Its point is only to spot specific kinds of biases.

Comment: @forest Not really sure why you're focusing specifically on runs tests.  That's simply an example test like the parking, compression or crushing etc.

Comment: I suspect forest was commenting on runs testing because you explicitly listed it in your answer. But forests comment would apply to any kind of such testing.

Comment: @EllaRose Well that's not quite right is it?  The "standardised" randomness tests specifically but sometimes indirectly detect bias and independence.  Otherwise they wouldn't be any good at detecting randomness and no one would use them. The simplest direct independence test is the correlation metric in ent or "convolve/FFT" if you roll your own tests. All compression tests pick up non independence as that's their forte.  It's entirely my personal failing, but I'm often confused with forest's  tangential comments :-(

Comment: @PaulUszak Pointing out a factual mistake in an answer is far from tangential.

Answer (score 3):

The one metric that generically matters in cryptography for a physical entropy source is the **min-entropy**: the exponent of the most probable outcome, in bits.  This depends on the physics of the entropy source.  As long as it exceeds 256, you can feed a sample through a typical preimage-resistant hash function such as SHAKE256, a conditioner, and you will have what is effectively a uniform random string fit for use as cryptographic key material.

(Sometimes the physical device is called a TRNG; sometimes the *composition* of the physical device and the conditioner like SHAKE256 is called a TRNG.)

If your device can't produce a sample with that much min-entropy at once, but it can produce a sequence of IID samples, then you can concatenate them.  The result may be much longer than 256 bits—even if it is very far from uniform in whatever is your favorite measure of statistical distance, what matters for cryptography is only that its min-entropy be at least 256 bits.

The NIST tests hypothesize various families of probabilistic models for the entropy source, fit parameters based on a sample, and then print the entropy of the *models* with the fitted parameters.  These models are very simple-minded and were designed *without knowledge of your device*, so they are at best a way to spot-check particularly obvious predictable distributions—so obvious an engineer thought of them without even knowing what your device is.  ([More details](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/58164) on how ‘entropy tests’ work.)

Generic measures computed on *samples* from your device, designed without reference to any model of the physics of your device, have very little value in studying the security of the system.  The min-entropy you advertise must be computed from a *specific probabilistic model* of the physics of the system to give any meaningful confidence in it.