# How can I estimate the amount of entropy (with JavaScript) that I'm seeding a CSPRNG with?

Tags: random-number-generator, entropy

I am trying to determine how much entropy is going into a specific CSPRNG in JavaScript, but I can't seem to find a pure-JS client-side implementation of an entropy estimator.

So, I need to find a way to estimate entropy locally with pure JavaScript.

If it helps, the entropy is in an array which should be easy to manipulate.

Comment: Estimate the entropy of what?

Comment: To grasp why that's not doable from a theoretical standpoint, see this obligatory [Dilbert strip](https://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25). More seriously, consider an hypothetical such entropy estimator fed with pieces taken from a CSPRNG (or, if that estimator is a pure function, just repeatedly fed with the same input taken from a perfect entropy source).

Answer (score 3):

If someone chooses to run your program with a seed that you can't predict but an adversary can, you won't be able to tell.  There is no way around this: nothing about the software can tell you what an adversary does or doesn't know; you can only use cryptography to ensure that *if* an adversary doesn't know a key and the message, *then* they can't decrypt the message.

In general, to estimate the entropy of a system, you need to have a model for how the system behaves.  This is [how all entropy estimation tools work](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/58164): they posit some parametric model for how the input data might have been generated; then use the data to fit parameters for that model; and finally spit out the entropy of the model with the fitted parameters.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain what you disagree with in this answer, Paul?